# I have an error message with server_id = ctx.message.guild.id

Tags: python, discord.py, nextcord

I have a problem and I can't find a solution. When I put `server_id = ctx.message.guild.id` in the following python source code, the terminal shows me:

```
nextcord.errors.ApplicationInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'guild'
```

Just because I put my command in /command.

Here is my code:

```py
@bot.slash_command()
async def name(ctx):
    server_id = ctx.message.guild.id
    await ctx.send(server_id)
```

with below imports:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from random import *
import os
from nextcord.ext import *
from nextcord import *
from nextcord.ui import *
```

I'm waiting for someone to help me and for the problem to be solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should decide on one library to use first off, I recommend discord.py, but it's up to you.

Anyways, the problem is that there is no message attached to the context, but you can just do `ctx.guild.id` and it will work fine (Assuming you actually have a correct if statement).